# Can't get git pull --recurse-submodules to work

Tags: git, git-submodules, pull

I'm trying to use submodules, but there's something I don't get.
I added the submodule :

```
$ git submodule add ssh://git@git.bureautique.itm.lan:4242/sdc-sasi/dss.git
$ git config -f .gitmodules submodule.dss.update merge
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
$ git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Add submodule"
$ git push
```

Then, someone else adds a file to the submodule, commits and push.
I can't get the update on my local repo :

```
$ git pull --recurse-submodules
###############################################################Récupération du sous-module dss
###############################################################Depuis ssh://git.bureautique.itm.lan:4242/sdc-sasi/dss
   3999c9c..1362f93  master     -> origin/master
```

But the link still points to the 3999c9c revision :

```
$ git submodule status
 3999c9c966f6fd058e0ecf9a2f3e947b609a7932 dss (heads/master)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't see where anybody added the new submodule history to the main project. `git add` adds specific content to the history you're building, file or submodule it's that specific content. If you want your main project using new content, whether it's in a file or in a submodule commit, `git add` what's new to the main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

> Then, someone else adds a file to the submodule, commits and push.

Does "someone" do that in a clone of the submodule repository, and push to the submodule repository ? If yes, then the command to use in your superproject clone is:

```bash
git submodule update --remote 
git add dss # the path of your submodule
git commit
```

(see the doc [`git submodule update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--filterltfilterspecgt--ltpathgt82308203) and the [`--remote` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---remote)).

The command `git pull --recurse-submodules` is the one to use if you want to update your *superproject* after someone changed the submodule pointer. I.e. after you do the above, your colleague can do `git pull --recurse-submodules` in their clone of the superproject to bring their working tree up to date (including their submodule working tree).

I highly recommend to read through the ["Git Submodules"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) chapter of the Pro Git book.

Comment: I did read this book, but obviously not carefully enough... Thank you !